# Stripe: param is missing or the value is empty: charges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, stripe-payments

I am trying to figure out how to integrate a custom Stripe form to barebones rails app but its's been a rough time thus far.

I am running into an error: `param is missing or the value is empty: charges`

This is my charges controller:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @charge = Charge.new
    end

    def create
      @charge = Charge.new
      if @charge.charging_card(charges_params)
        redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Contribution was recorded succesfully!"
      else
        redirect_to about_path, :notice => "Transaction was not able to be recorded"
      end
    end

    def charges_params
        params.require(:charges).permit(:stripe_card_token)
    end


end
```

This is my charges view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Stripe Getting Started Form</title>

  <!-- The required Stripe lib -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

  <!-- jQuery is used only for this example; it isn't required to use Stripe -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('I put my own test key here');

    var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
      var $form = $('#payment-form');

      if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        // and re-submit
        $form.get(0).submit();
      }
    };

    jQuery(function($) {
      $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>


<%= form_for @charge do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-2 columns">
          <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number:" %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-10 columns">
          <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, :data => {:stripe => 'number'} %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-2 columns">
          <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV):" %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-10 columns end">
          <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, :data => {:stripe => 'cvc'} %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-2 columns">
          <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration:" %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 medium-3 columns">
          <%= select_month nil, {name: nil, id: "card_month"}, :data => {:stripe => 'exp-month'} %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 medium-3 columns">
          <%= select_year nil, {name: nil, id: "card_year"}, :data => {:stripe => 'exp-year'} %>
        </div>

      <div id="stripe_error">
        <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-actions small-9 small-offset-2 columns">
        <%= f.submit "Donate" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my charges model:

```
class Charge < ActiveRecord::Base

Stripe.api_key = "I put my key here"

attr_accessor :stripe_card_token 


def charging_card(charge)
    begin
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => 325, # amount in cents, again
        :currency => "usd",
        :card => stripe_card_token,
        :description => "payinguser@example.com"
      )
    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
        logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    end


    end
end
```

This is my schema table:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140723082502) do

  create_table "charges", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "stripe_card_token"
    t.decimal  "amount"
  end

end
```

This is my server logs:

```
Started POST "/charges" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-23 01:57:45 -0700
Processing by ChargesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4FJAw5RTi1K2n3mC0lccoJ2iaDeQxfXRMGqi2kojsbk=", "date"=>{"month"=>"1",
 "year"=>"2015"}, "commit"=>"Donate"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 4ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: charge):
  app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:17:in `charges_params'
  app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:9:in `create'


  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/template
s/rescues/_source.erb (71.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/template
s/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/template
s/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/template
s/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (221.1ms)
```

I guess I am not understanding why charges in my strong parameters is empty?

Any other advice or suggestions that you can spot from my code that could help me in accomplishing this project would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your server log generated?

Comment: @Pavan I've just added my log output to the end of the question. Thanks.

Comment: This line `@charge = Charge.new` in your create action should be `@charge = Charge.new(charges_params)` i guess.

Comment: And i didn't see the `save` in your `create` action,what does this line `if @charge.charging_card(charges_params)` do?

Comment: When I do @charge = Charge.new(charges_params) I get an error as soon as I visit my charges view.. I get this: param is missing or the value is empty: charge

Comment: Hmmm how could I go about adding the save? You are correct that seems to be missing

Comment: Before i go editing my answer,i want to know what does this line `if @charge.charging_card(charges_params)` do?

Comment: @pavan I have no idea! I was trying to pass the method in the model but I got utterly confused by what I was trying to do that now I am unsure what my purpose was with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Strong Parameters to something like this:

```
def charges_params
  if params[:charges] && params[:charges][:stripe_card_token].present?
    params.require(:charges).permit(:stripe_card_token)
  end
end
```

Comment: That worked.. Why did this work? Unfortunately now I am seeing another problem in my logs saying 'Stripe error while creating customer: You must supply either a card or a customer id'

Comment: it bcz your not sending the params "charges" to create